# on and upon- their difference

Tags: prepositions

Is the use of upon correct in the following sentence?

There is a book upon the desk.

Also, is there any difference between on and upon in the following?

He stood on/upon the rock.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: *Upon* is a more formal, elegant way of saying *on*, that is regrettably slightly old-fashioned. It is preserved in many English place names such as *Stratford-upon-Avon*, *Newcastle-upon-Tyne*, *Kingston-upon-Thames* etc. It is always helpful if you are writing a song or a poem, and you need an extra syllable to make a particular line scan e.g. [*Upon the roof* by The Drifters 1962](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_on_the_Roof_(song)). Though in that case it is written as two words - *Up on the roof*.

Answer (score -1):

Though "on" and "upon" share about 92.3% the same meaning, the use of "upon" carries with it a slight tinge of depndency that "on" may lack.
I can stand on the corner, but seriously doubt I will stand UPON the corner. However, "I stand UPON my principles", bears a little more punch than "standing ON principles."